# stored procedures not recoverd after restoring database backup file in c# winforms application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a data base called TestDB in sql server that includes several tables and stored procedures.
i created a backup file from that called TestDB.bac, after that i created a c# winforms application to restore it from app and recovering operation runs successfully but there is a problem. after the recovery is complete, most of my stored procedures is gone, this happening by restoring from c# app and when i try to restore from SSMS all of them comes back. how can i handle this issue??

here is my function that runs recovering codes:

```
public void Restore(string path)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string UseMaster = "USE master";
                SqlCommand UseMasterCommand = new SqlCommand(UseMaster, connection);
                UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string Alter1 = @"ALTER DATABASE [TestDB] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate";
                SqlCommand Alter1Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter1, connection);
                Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string Restore = string.Format("Restore database TestDB from disk='{0}' with replace", path);
                SqlCommand RestoreCmd = new SqlCommand(Restore, connection);
                RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string Alter2 = @"ALTER DATABASE [TestDB] SET Multi_User";
                SqlCommand Alter2Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter2, connection);
                Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

and here is screenshots:

after recovering by c# app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUiX7.png)

after recovering by SSMS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1EBy.png)

i would appreciate it if you could help

i tried to delete database and recreated it with same name and put all data in new database from my backup file but didn't work.

Comment: script the restore code from ssms and compare it with the c# code. i'm pretty sure you're restoring wrong backup

Comment: all the tables and 4 of procedures recovering by running c# app and i have no other backup files.

Comment: Just refresh the SSMS explorer with the refresh button at the top.

Comment: Side notes: instead of doing `USE master`  just change the connection string to connect to that database. Instead of `from disk='{0}'` and injecting the filename, use a proper parameter `from disk = @filename` and then `RestoreCmd.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 261).Value = path;`. Even if you want to use string formatting, it's easier to use string interpolation with a `$`. The `SqlCommand` objects need `using` to dispose them. Note that you don't need multiple commands, you can do it all in one batch.

Comment: thank you @AaronBertrand . your suggestions solved my problem. the problem was about INIT and NOINIT backups.